# drawMatches() throws CvException: Unsupported destination image

Tags: java, opencv

I'm drawing matches between my logo and my input image. The `drawMatches` function didn't work and thrown exception.

Here is my code:

```
Mat input = Imgcodecs.imread(inputAddress);
Mat logo = Imgcodecs.imread(logoList.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem());

SIFT detector = SIFT.create(4, 3);

MatOfKeyPoint logoKeypoint = new MatOfKeyPoint();
MatOfKeyPoint inputKeypoint = new MatOfKeyPoint();
detector.detect(logo, logoKeypoint);
detector.detect(input, inputKeypoint);

Mat logoDes = new Mat();
Mat inputDes = new Mat();
detector.compute(logo, logoKeypoint, logoDes);
detector.compute(input, inputKeypoint, inputDes);

DescriptorMatcher matcher = DescriptorMatcher.create(DescriptorMatcher.BRUTEFORCE);
MatOfDMatch matches = new MatOfDMatch();
matcher.match(logoDes, inputDes, matches);

HighGui.namedWindow("matches", 1);
Mat imgMatches = new Mat();
Features2d.drawMatches(logo, logoKeypoint, input, inputKeypoint, matches, imgMatches);
HighGui.imshow("matches", imgMatches);
```

The exception:

```
Caused by: CvException [org.opencv.core.CvException: cv::Exception: OpenCV(4.1.0) C:\Users\hennm\Downloads\opencv-4.1.0\modules\features2d\src\draw.cpp:128: error: (-2:Unspecified error) in function 'void __cdecl cv::_prepareImage(const class cv::debug_build_guard::_InputArray &,const class cv::Mat &)'
> Unsupported destination image:
>     'dst.type() == CV_8UC3 || dst.type() == CV_8UC4'
> where
>     'dst.type()' is 0 (CV_8UC1)
]
    at org.opencv.features2d.Features2d.drawMatches_4(Native Method)
    at org.opencv.features2d.Features2d.drawMatches(Features2d.java:116)
    at sample.Controller.match(Controller.java:102)
```

Where `sample.Controller.match(Controller.java:102)` is the line `Features2d.drawMatches(logo, logoKeypoint, input, inputKeypoint, matches, imgMatches);`

Comment: The error message says that the destination `Mat` which is `imgMatches` in your case, must be a 3 or 4 channel `Mat`, but you are passing it a single channel `Mat`. You can verify this by checking the number of channels of `imgMatches` Mat before calling the method.

Comment: Could you suggest me a way? I tried to change it through `Imgproc.cvtColor(imgMatches, imgMatches, Imgproc.COLOR_GRAY2BGR);` but it gave another error: `assertion failed) !_src.empty() in function 'cvtcolor'`. I switched to `imgMatches.convertTo(imgMatches, CvType.CV_8UC3);` but it didn't change the Mat's channel.

Comment: You can pass in the number of channels and a default color while creating the matrix in constructor itself, Please look into the `Mat` documentation

Comment: Thank you, I fixed it myself as the address argument from `imread()` is mistakenly an URI, not a directory path.